# How to login Two different tables with single login form in mvc(both Admin and user want to login in single login)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have User table and Employee table, but I have only one login form for user(Admin). I want to login Employee also from same login page please help me as soon as possible? In MVC.

Answer (score 1):

First check if `username` exits in the `User` table, if it does then match the `password` and return accordingly. If doesn't exist then check `username` in `employee` table and match `password`. If not found in both tables, return user doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank u itz useful for me

Answer (score 1):

I prefer having all my users in one table, then assigning them the Admin role if required.

But if that is not an option, check if the user exists in the admin table, if not, check the users table. If still not, don't log him in. Otherwise do the rest of the login process.

Answer (score -1):

**My preference is:**

1. All users should be into a single table. And user table needs to contain a column "isAdmin[bool]".
2. when user press on the login button with correct username and password, system will check the role. if isAdmin == true then the user should log into the system with admin functionalists as well as the regular employee functionalists. Because a admin is also an employee.
3. when isAdmin==false the the user should log into the system with only employee functionalists.
4. Try to learn more about role based authentication.

Thanks